# why my bootstrap custon-file class not showing like the example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to show bootstrap view and this is the example in bootstrap docs

[image]

but this is what my view looks like

[image]

I showing it with safari and chrome but it shows the same. did anyone know why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be missed the css links

```js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <form action="">
    <div class="custom-file mb-3">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you! it only need the `maxcdn` one for me.